# Multiple saga mapping of a single message

Tags: nservicebus, saga

I need to map one message to multiple saga instances. 
how can i do it?

i thought to an utility service that receives that message and sends copies of it to all saga instances. But this solution requires the knowledge from this service of all sagaIds.

Comment: Can you describe what your saga is doing?

Comment: i have an application with wich users can organize outfit and fashion item collections. When the collection is complete system must get all technical and logistic information about it. A fashion item collection can contain thousands items and i need excellent performance. I have 2 orchestration services. The first for every collection, the second for every item. An item can reside to more than one collection and when it's available in the warehouse every collect must be notified about it. So i need one to map the notify message to all saga istances connected to the collections that contain it.

Comment: Do the collections contain all the item data or do they hold a reference to it?

Comment: I designed the collections with all item data, does it make difference?

Comment: It may, I guess a better question would be what happens once items become available?  Is this to handle back orders?

Comment: Yes you guess, when an item is available i can send the order confirmation and process with the shipping!

Comment: Do you have knowledge of approximately when the inventory will arrive?  If you did, then in your saga you could request a timeout for that period and check the inventory again.  If it still wasn't there, then you would keep requesting timeouts until it was resolved.  If it can't be resolved, then maybe you can ask the user to pick something else.

Comment: Yes i do, but with this feature how can i figure out the missing multiple mapping saga message problem?

Comment: Why do you need the saga ids then? Wouldn't it be enough to map them through the [Unique] property of the saga - which you should have pr. item in your collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't currently supported on a single endpoint. If you want multiple sagas to handle the same message, that message needs to be processed by multiple endpoints.

Can you design your solution differently not to need multiple sagas to be invoked per message?

Comment: Up to now i can't, i designed different notify services that are indipendent from the saga istance id but are connected to the other saga properties. Instead i thought about handling the message from a not orchestration service hosted by the same endpoint that broadcast it to all saga istances. But i can't figure out how to get all saga ids..

Comment: It would be very nice if this could make its way onto the roadmap for future versions. This is a really useful concept.

Comment: @DaveNichol we've currently got a development branch that has this functionality on it and are evaluating which release we'll be able to pull this into.

Comment: I'm a little embarrassed that I might have misread this question. My need isn't about having multiple instances of the same saga responding to a single message, but _multiple separate saga implementations_ responding to the same message. Does NSB allow that? Sorry for the confusion...

Comment: @DaveNichol yes, that is supported, though we have an issue reported when someone has 7 saga types running together with Raven as the persistence: https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/issues/413